# Talos, syntax to select best_model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, talos

I'm running a toy model for learning, on Ubuntu 21.10, in a conda environment that comprises python 3.74, keras 2.4.3 and talos 1.0, among many other packages.  I've run a talos scan using this code:

```
jam1 = talos.Scan(data,
                  labels[0,],
                  model = DLAt,
                  params = ParamsJam1,
                  experiment_name = "DL2Outputs"
                  )
```

However I've tried everything I can find but can not find correct syntax to select the best model using talos.best_model.

```
bm = talos.best_model(metric='loss', asc=False)
```

just gets this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'talos' has no attribute 'best_model'
```

Is this not the correct function to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best model isn't saved in the package, it's saved in the Scan object:

```
bm.best_model(metric='loss', asc=False)
```